# Kerio EWS differences to real Exchange EWS?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

One of our customers uses Kerio Connect. Therefore he told us that it offers somekind of EWS Interface.

Does somebody know how compatible this Interface is compared to the real EWS Interface ?

Is it possible to let run a program which is coded to Exchange (2007 / 2010) with "Kerio" EWS?

Does anyone can give me a link to a documentation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation is actually a subset of Exchange 2007 EWS necessary to synchronize emails and groupware items to Outlook for Mac. As of Connect 8.0.X, it is unlikely that a program coded against Exchange would work with Kerio Connect without changes. If you need a help with EWS, you can ask on Kerio forums (http://forums.kerio.com/).